# cant get the database updated based on changes in datatable bound to gridview using adapter.update command

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

I am using two gridviews with buttons to swap rows between the two. now what i am trying to do is, make changes into gridviews, trycast them into datatables adn then use dataadapter.update(datatable) command to update database. but the changes just wont happen in database. Here is me code. thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub SubmitToDbButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitToDbButton.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table_1", con)
    Dim builder1 As New SqlCommandBuilder(da1)
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=N0PCRIM9L3RYX1;Initial Catalog=RandomFormDB;Integrated Security=True"
        con.Open()
        da1.Fill(dt1)
        dt1 = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable) 'datatable gets new rows here
        dt1.AcceptChanges()
        da1.Update(dt1)
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

here is the full code. i am new to vb, so this is really missing me up. the datatable and the table returned from the query have same columns. but somehow, dataadapter isn't able to understand that. how to do that?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim L As Load_Data
    Public Sub LoadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click
        L = New Load_Data()
        L.Load()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LTRButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LTRButton.Click       
        Dim dt1 As DataTable   'moves selected row from left gridview to right one
        Dim dt2 As DataTable
        Dim str As String = Nothing
        dt1 = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
        dt2 = TryCast(DataGridView2.DataSource, DataTable)
        Dim selecetedId As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
        Dim row As DataRow
        For Each row In dt1.Rows
            If row.Item("ID") = selecetedId Then
                dt2.ImportRow(row)
                dt1.Rows.Remove(row)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub RTLButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RTLButton.Click          
        Dim dt1 As DataTable  'moves selected row from right gridview to left one
        Dim dt2 As DataTable
        Dim str As String = Nothing
        dt1 = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
        dt2 = TryCast(DataGridView2.DataSource, DataTable)
        Dim selecetedId As String = DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
        Dim row As DataRow
        For Each row In dt2.Rows
            If row.Item("ID") = selecetedId Then
                dt1.ImportRow(row)
                dt2.Rows.Remove(row)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SubmitToDbButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitToDbButton.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection  'this sub submits changes to database
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable      'problem lies in this function
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table_1", con)
        Dim builder1 As New SqlCommandBuilder(da1)
        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=N0PCRIM9L3RYX1;Initial Catalog=RandomFormDB;Integrated Security=True"
            con.Open()
            da1.Fill(dt1)
            dt1 = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
            'dt1.AcceptChanges()
            da1.Fill(dt1)
            da1.Update(dt1)
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Load_Data
    Public Sub Load()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table_1; Select * from Table_2", con)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=N0PCRIM9L3RYX1;Initial Catalog=RandomFormDB;Integrated Security=True"
            con.Open()
            da.Fill(ds)
            Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            Form1.DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why would TryCast add a new row?

Comment: plz see full code, i have now posted. due to multiple swaps between the two gridviews, datatable undergoes multiple row changes. trycasting directly from the gridview gives me the changed table. but da.update(dt1) isn't working for this. if not like this, how can i do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to [AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) has this effect on the rows of your DataTable.

Every row that has its [RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) set to something different from [DataRowState.Unchanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) will be set to DataRowState.Unchanged except for  the rows with DataRowState.Deleted that will be removed from the table.

If you call the Update method of the Adapter after calling AcceptChanges then you are effectively removing any possibility to update your datasource. The property that says to your Update method which rows need to be updated has been reset.

So, to fix your problem just remove the AcceptChanges call. **But there is another problem**. You have created an `SqlCommandBuilder` when the SqlDataAdapter was bind to the first table (The one that you have loaded with `SELECT * FROM Table_1`), now you are trying to update a different table with probably a different name and different columns. So your update command is doomed.

It seems that you need to rebuild the SqlDataAdapter or use the one that you have used to fill the `DataGridView1`

**EDIT**
Looking at your updated code I can find two problems.
The first one is simple to solve, just remove the double call to Fill in your Submit code

```
Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table_1", con)
Dim builder1 As New SqlCommandBuilder(da1)
Try
    con.ConnectionString = "...."
    con.Open()
    dt1 = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    da1.Update(dt1)
    con.Close()
Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

The second problem is more complex. When you click to move a row from a grid to the another one you use two methods that leave your datasources (the datatables) unchanged. Both [ImportRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.datarowcollection.remove(v=vs.100).aspx), if you look closely to the documentation, have an effect on the RowState of the rows involved leaving the Update in the condition to not be able to update anything.

You should try to use instead

```
....
For Each row In dt2.Rows
    If row.Item("ID") = selecetedId Then
        dt1.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray)
        row.Delete()
        Exit For
    End If
Next
....
```

Probably this approach will cause other problems if you try to move back a row from the second grid back to the first row, but now I am not in the condition to test this. If you get some error about accessing a deleted row then you should add a check to verify if the loaded row is not in the collection of the Deleted rows (use the GetChanges method).

Comment: i think you're right. so, i've posted full code above. plz suggest how can i do this. there can be multiple swaps between the two gridviews, thats why i trycasted, but i guess it doesn't work like this. Plz suggest a way out of this.

Comment: i guess rowstate doesnt change to 'changed', when i trycast. thats why it doesnt get updated into the database. how else to do this?

Comment: Two calls to Fill in `SubmitToDbButton_Click`? Not a chance that you have any changed row after the second fill.

Comment: plz guide me a lil then. i am lost here. what can i do?

Comment: take this scenario. there are two gridviews in front of me. left one draws data from one table and another one takes data from another table. i select a row from right grid and press rtl button. i see it coming in the left gridview. but how to update this change into database??

Comment: Many many thanks Steve. it worked. thanks for making me aware me about this concept of state change in rows. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

U need to fill the adapter after the table is loaded hence

```
     da1.Fill(dt1)
    dt1 = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable) 'datatable gets new rows here
```

should change to

```
    dt1 = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
     da1.Fill(dt1)
```

Comment: it didnt help. duplicated the rows in gridview instead.